# What is MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams params in getFramesAtIndex()?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve all the frames from a video. For that I am using `getFramesAtIndex()` in `MediaMetadataRetriever`.

I am not sure about the third parameter in the function, which is `MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams params`.
Can you explain the third parameter with an example. I tried to look in Android documentation, but there are no examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFramesAtIndex(int,%20int,%20android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams)) for `MediaMetadataRetriever#getFramesAtIndex`:

> This method retrieves a consecutive set of video frames starting at
>   the specified index. It should only be called after
>   setDataSource(Context, Uri). If the caller intends to retrieve more
>   than one consecutive video frames, this method is preferred over
>   getFrameAtIndex(int,
>   android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams) for efficiency.
>   After the bitmaps are returned, you can query the actual parameters
>   that were used to create the bitmaps from the BitmapParams argument,
>   for instance to query the bitmap config used for the bitmaps with
>   BitmapParams#getActualConfig.

The bitmap params allows you to specify a preferred bitmap config to be returned.

**Example:**

```
val bitmapParams = MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams()

// Set your preferred bitmap config e.g.
bitmapParams.preferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565

val frameIndex = 0
val numFrames = 10
val frames = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFramesAtIndex(frameIndex, numFrames, bitmapParams)

// Can now query actual config of bitmap frames returned
bitmapParams.actualConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFramesAtIndex()` is overloaded. If you don't have specific requirements for image quality, then you could use the [two-arguments version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFramesAtIndex(int,%20int)) of the method:

```
public List<Bitmap> getFramesAtIndex (int frameIndex, 
                int numFrames)
```

which requires no `BitmapParams`. This is choice provides the simplest code as possible. There are two reasons why you might want to use the [three-arguments version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFramesAtIndex(int,%20int,%20android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams)) of the method:

- Specific image quality requirements
- Efficiency, as the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFramesAtIndex(int,%20int,%20android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams)) says:

> If the caller intends to retrieve more than one consecutive video frames, this method is preferred over `getFrameAtIndex(int, android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams)` for efficiency

To answer your question, the simplest usage of the three-arguments version is

```
getFramesAtIndex (myFrameIndex, 
                myNumFrames, 
                new MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams());
```

because, if you look at the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams#public-constructors_1) of `BitmapParams`, the default constructor

> Creates a default BitmapParams object. By default, it uses Bitmap.Config#ARGB_8888 as the preferred bitmap config.

This is the preferrable choice in most cases, as discussed in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888). As for non-default cases, suppose you want to specify the [`ALPHA_8`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ALPHA_8) option instead of the default `ARGB_8888`. Then the code is as follows

```
getFramesAtIndex (myFrameIndex, 
                myNumFrames, 
                new MediaMetadataRetriever.BitmapParams()
                   .setPreferredConfig(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8));
```

Hope that helps.